# Move data on top if a value exist in column of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like

```
id name isp
z  god  promoted
d  desk anyname
f  zzz  promoted
s  df   nope
ds ddd  det
```

i want the output dataframe to have the values on top if their isp column value is "promoted"
so the output dataframe will look like below:

```
id name isp
z  god promoted
f  zzz promoted
d  desk anyname
s  df   nope
ds ddd  det
```

Any help thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[df.isp.ne('promoted').argsort()]
Out[25]: 
   id  name       isp
0   z   god  promoted
2   f   zzz  promoted
1   d  desk   anyname
3   s    df      nope
4  ds   ddd       det
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `assign` and `np.where` to createa temporary column `sort` which you sort with and drop later

```
import numpy as np
       df=df.assign(sort=np.where(df.isp=='promoted',1,2)).sort_values(by='sort', ascending=True).drop(columns=['sort'])
        print(df)

  id  name       isp
0   z   god  promoted
2   f   zzz  promoted
1   d  desk   anyname
3   s    df      nope
4  ds   ddd       det
```